# Is there a singular countable noun to mean one fork, one knife and, optionally, one spoon, as would be used by each person partaking of a meal?

Tags: nouns

I am referring to the word which would fill the blank in the following sentence:

> May I have a _____, please?

Answer (score 4):

It’s called a *place setting*—table service for one person.

https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=place%20setting

In most restaurants, it would also include a napkin, some dishes, and a glass of water.

A restaurant would understand a request for utensils to mean knife, fork, and perhaps spoon.

Cutlery is another option specific to these utensils.

Comment: If you were asking for it in a restaurant, you would say "May I have some cutlery?"